# C# how to use yield operator during recursive call?

Tags: c#, recursion, yield

I have a recursive method for building combinations of arrays. The method works great, but requires that the results array be fully allocated in memory prior to iterating. I read about the yield operator, and because it is using IEnumerator<> it appears that it should return one result at a time, vastly shrinking memory consumption. I've tried various schemes to 'yield' a result. However, none of them are successful. I would like to know how to use the yield operator to achieve the desired results.

Here is the code that builds combinations:

```
public static class CombinationArray
{
    private static int _resultsIndex;
    private static int[][] _results;
    public static int GetBinCoeff(int n, int k)
    {
        int r = 1;
        int d;
        if (k > n) return 0;
        for (d = 1; d <= k; d++)
        {
            r *= n--;
            r /= d;
        }
        return r;
    }
    public static int[][] GetCombinations(int[] elements, int length)
    {
        _resultsIndex = 0;
        int numResults = GetBinCoeff(elements.Length, length);
        // observe that here I fully allocate the results array[][]:
        _results = new int[numResults][];
        for (int i = 0; i < numResults; i++)
            _results[i] = new int[length];
        Combinations(elements, length, 0, new int[length]);
        return _results;
    }
    private static void Combinations(int[] input, int len, int startPosition, int[] result)
    {
        if (len == 0)
        {
            Array.Copy(result, _results[_resultsIndex++], result.Length);
            return;
        }
        for (int i = startPosition; i <= input.Length - len; i++)
        {
            result[result.Length - len] = input[i];
            Combinations(input, len - 1, i + 1, result);
        }
    }
}
```

and the above code can be called like this:

```
[Test]
public void CombinationsUsingArraysOnly()
{
    int[] items = {1, 2, 3};
    var results = CombinationArray.GetCombinations(items, 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < results.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        string output = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < results[i].Length; j++)
            output += results[i][j] + ",";
        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }
}
```

and the results output like this:

```
1,2,
1,3,
2,3,
```

I have tried the following, without success:

```
private static IEnumerable<int[]> Combinations(int[] input, int len, int startPosition, int[] result)
{
    if (len == 0)
    {
        yield return result;
    }
    for (int i = startPosition; i <= input.Length - len; i++)
    {
        result[result.Length - len] = input[i];
        Combinations(input, len - 1, i + 1, result);
    }
}
```

...but when I 'foreach' the return 'IEnumerable<>' it acts as if the count==0 and I get no results. I have tried other ways of handling the yield but none of them "yield" results (bad pun).

Comment: You aren't using your recursive call to `Combinations`. Normally you'd have another loop over it `yield returning` all the value from the recursion.

Comment: Could you please provide an example and I'll try to code it?

Comment: See also http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26050/Permutations-Combinations-and-Variations-using-C-G and there's a nuget package for it.

Comment: @Ian: specifically, I do not want to use C# generics (other than the IEnumerable to allow yield to work). I want to use recursion. Please answer within the scope of my question.

Comment: the code project link is a comment not an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate your recursive call also. In your code, you only return the base case while the rest of the executions don't return anything.

```
private static IEnumerable<int[]> Combinations(int[] input, int len, int startPosition, int[] result)
{
    if (len == 0)
    {
        yield return result;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = startPosition; i <= input.Length - len; i++)
        {
            result[result.Length - len] = input[i];

            //// You need to return the results of your recursive call
            foreach (var combination in Combinations(input, len - 1, i + 1, result))
            {
                yield return combination;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: works for first iteration, but the second iteration "index was outside the bound of the array". len==0 causing result.Length - len to be 2; which exceeds the array size.

Comment: It should be `if (len == 0) { yield return result; } else { for... }`. Add the Else clause.

Comment: @thepirat000: that fixed it. thank you. I went ahead and edited Vlad's answer.